# Why two of my <li> are merging?

Tags: html, css, html-lists

i am making a menu with `<ul>`, I need to have 2 buttons in the same `<li>` but when I do it, the 2 `<li>` are merging. Why and how to avoid this ?

Picture is better than long text :

[image][image]

this menu is produce with this html :

```
<div id="EditArticleMenu" class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 col-xs-4">
        <ul>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <h3>Edition</h3>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-upload icons-left"> </span>Publier
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tasks icons-left"></span>Options de publication
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down icons-right"> </span>
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt icons-left"> </span>Enregistrer dans les brouillons
            </button>

            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open icons-left"> </span>Aperçu
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-tags icons-left"> </span>Tags et catégories
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-book icons-left"> </span>Lier une oeuvre
            </button>
        </li>
        <li class="menu-item">
            <button class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-picture icons-left"> </span>Ajouter un média
            </button>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
```

The CSS :

```
.menu-item {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 10px;
}

li {
    display: block; // No changes when list-item
}
```

Comment: please upload css file

Comment: Are they displayed as `inline-block`? Change it to `block` or `list-item`.

Comment: yes li was displayed in block, no changes with list-item. Editing question.

Comment: @Paulie_D Please read the question

Comment: Please provide all the code required to replicate the issue. The code you have provided so far does not reflect the problem you show in your images. https://jsfiddle.net/eLhn1ahq/

Comment: Trying to, but i can't upload everything since I have a confidential agreement.

Comment: @GuillaumeBeauvois Have you been able to create a reproducible example of this issue?

Comment: @HiddenHobbes no unfortunately. the problem came from the crossing of the many css template used in the product. Due to a short dead-line we have decided to put on button per row. Thanks for your concern ! I Is there a way to close the question ? Should i delete ?

Comment: No problem, I was interested to see what the problem was! Well, given that you're not able to include the code to replicate the issue and the answers don't solve your problem I think it would be ok to delete the question in this instance.

Answer (score 0):

use padding

```
.menu-item {
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: padding didn't worked. It's not a "marge merging" then.

Comment: add display:block in class "menu-item"

Answer (score 0):

Add this to your CSS:

```
.menu-item button {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: adding button to the css didn't change the result :/

Comment: `.menu-item button {
    display: block !important;  width: 100% !important;
}`

Comment: The problem is that beside the fact that buttons are using inline-block display you also used some col classes which are setting some width and float: left; on the button. So you need to force that button to use display block and width 100% to make sure there is only one button/row.

Answer (score 0):

ok as I guess you are trying to get the following layout. here, you have given button size `md-6` for both buttons which denotes that button has 50% width of total so its merging. If you make `md-12` for both buttons it will align block

```
 <li class="menu-item">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-download-alt icons-left"> </span>Enregistrer dans les brouillons
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-lg col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                    <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open icons-left"> </span>Aperçu
                </button>
            </li>
```